# Converting Mean Customer Satisfaction to 2TB Score

Tags: correlation, business-intelligence

In Previous years we have reported on mean satisfaction for customer satisfaction.  Previous years have been calculated on a 5 point scale.  We have moved to T2B satisfaction ratings with the scale now 1-10. (Satisfied and Very Satisfied representing the top 2 boxes).  In order to show trending, I need to know how to convert mean satisfaction to a T2B equivalent.  What formula will help accomplish this?

Comment: Why would you think that's possible? You're asking a different question, with a different response scale and throwing most of the data to extract very different summaries (mean on some arbitrary scale versus percentage on the top 2 boxes).

Comment: Also, your definition of “top 2 boxes” is a bit puzzling and unorthodox. Typically “top 2 boxes” is a (questionable) way to summarize data from 5-point response scales. The notion is that there is a clear middle in the scale and anybody picking the top 2 boxes means something like “better than average”. The 1-10 format sounds more like NPS, which is highly problematic and definitely not comparable with a 5-point satisfaction rating (although I suppose someone somewhere probably tried some linear regression on data like this).

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.